# Number of workers for Node.js cluster

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I read a few articles about Node.js cluster and normally in examples number of workers matches a number of CPU cores.

What happens if I specify more? Will it bring any benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have available resources on the system, then you can take advantage of those resources through having multiple node workers.

If you have too much workers, the OS will have to share the resources among your workers - no advantages here.

That's why in your examples the amount of workers matches the number of CPU cores.

Comment: As I understand, each node worker has sort of queue of tasks which is processed sequentially. Therefore a CPU core is constantly used by the worker. If there are more workers than CPU cores then that worker is interrupted time to time by another one which means there is no any benefit. But this article makes me confused:
http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/
I found that Heroku dyno CPU has 4 cores but in this article (Cluster section) 5 to 7 workers were created. Am I right that it is not necessary to have that many?